# Deserialize keystone json response using newtonsoft json.net

Tags: c#, json, json.net, openstack, keystone

I am writing C# code to access a Swift object store. The first step is to authenticate the user against the Keystone identity service. I’ve done this successfully and get the following JSON string in response.

```
{
  "access":{
    "token":{
      "expires": "2013-10-22T17:09:46Z",
      "id": "c6f69256db4d45af819cc42b54e18f69",
      "tenant": {
        "enabled": true,
        "id": "7b9a902423a582c9eda266dcf3ad697420c1c3ff9429b1dfd255152f3bf2098f",
        "name": "tenant1"}
      },
    "serviceCatalog":[
      {
        "endpoints": 
        [
          {
            "adminURL": "http://mysite.com:8888/",
            "region": "RegionOne",
            "internalURL":"http://mysite.com:8888/v1/AUTH_7b9a902423a52d255152f3bf2098f",
            "id": "4ec67a5dcd034a68ad08a2fc133a8dc0",
            "publicURL": http://mysite.com:8888/v1/AUTH_7b9a902423a52d255152f3bf2098f
          }
        ],
        "endpoints_links": [],
        "type": "object-store",
        "name": "swift"}
    ],
    "user":{
      "username": "user1",
      “roles_links": [],
      "id": "324c2ae86fff69d22629320cdf589f417b9a902423a582c9eda266dcf3ad6974",
      "roles":[
        {"name": "tenant1"},
        {"name": "Likewise Users"},
        {"name": "tenant1"}
      ],
      "name": "user1"
    },
    "metadata":{
      "is_admin": 0,
      "roles":[
        "7b9a902423a582c9eda266dcf3ad697420c1c3ff9429b1dfd255152f3bf2098f",
        "7b9a902423a582c9eda266dcf3ad6974104ff417849b613ce82c28d1562f82c8",
        "7b9a902423a582c9eda266dcf3ad697420c1c3ff9429b1dfd255152f3bf2098f"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I have code using JSON.net 4.0.3 that takes uses a rather crude approach (my code, not newtonsoft) to pulling the information out of the JSON and into a collection of dictionaries that I can use to reference the attributes I need. My code looks like this.

```
var accessRoot = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(jsonResponse);
var accessItems = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(accessRoot["access"].ToString());
var tokens = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(accessItems["token"].ToString());
var tokenTenantDict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(tokens["tenant"].ToString());
var serviceCatalog = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(accessItems["serviceCatalog"].ToString());
var user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(accessItems["user"].ToString());
var metadata = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(accessItems["metadata"].ToString());
string tokenExpiration = tokens["expires"].ToString();
string tokenId = tokens["id"].ToString();
string tokenTenant = tokens["tenant"].ToString();
string userUsername = user["username"].ToString();
string tenantId = tokenTenantDict["id"];
string userId = user["id"].ToString();
string userName = user["name"].ToString();
```

What I’m looking for is a more elegant solution that probably includes a class definition that I can deserialize the JSON string into. I haven’t found anything like this and I expect the answer will be a big help to others programming to the Keystone interface. 
Thank you for any suggested solutions.

Comment: The [openstack.net](http://openstacknetsdk.org) library should support the operations you need, and is readily available.

Comment: Great, I will look into the library. In the meantime I answered using [json2csharp.com](http://json2csharp.com) Will post the solution in a few hours when the SO restriction lifts on newbies answering their own questions

Answer (score 0):

The reason this does not work right is that there is an error in the JSON string. I use the on-line checker to validate a JSON string that is received before using it in my code.

http://www.freeformatter.com/json-validator.html

Comment: Hi Martyn, thanks for the quick reply. Apparently I deleted the character in my effort to format the string. However, what I am looking for is a suggested class layout that can be used to deserialize the json string into. I am actively working on the class but am struggling with it.